# How to set PVM's environment?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pvm

i'm using Ubuntu v11.04. How to set PVM's environment variable ?

in the handbook, it writes, "the easiest method is to set these variables in your .cshrc file", but i can't find any .cshrc file. i find cshrc.stub.

if anyone has ever used PVM?

Comment: PVM as in Parallel Virtual Machine, the really ancient API for distributed memory parallel computing? That's the only guess I'd have for something that still references `.cshrc` as if it were common today. What software still uses PVM? Note that cshrc is useless if you don't set csh as your shell.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used PVM, but the file that you're looking for depends on which shell you use.  If you use csh, then .cshrc can be found in your home directory.  Note that it's a hidden file so you'll need to do `ls -a` to list it.  If you use bash shell, then you should find .bashrc in your home directory.

To set an environment variable in csh, you'll use the `setenv`command.  For bash, it'll be `export`.